# laravel validation according to table data

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i have made profile update page , if user's account_type = 1 i mustn't use tax_number , company_name and tax_administration but user's account_type = 1 i must use like this validate :
for example 'tax_number'  => 'required|max:10'

how can i do it the short way ?

may you help me ?

My Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(User $user)
    {
        if ( $this->isMethod('POST') ) {
            return [
                'name'                  => 'required|min:2|max:100',
                'surname'               => 'required|min:2|max:100',
                'email'                 => ['required','min:6','max:50',Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore(auth()->id())],
                'phone'                 => 'required|min:6|max:14',
                'image'                 => 'sometimes|nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:5120',
                'id_no'                 => 'required|max:16',
                'address'               => 'required|min:6|max:250',
                'country'               => 'required|max:100',
                'city'                  => 'required|max:100',
                'county'                => 'required|max:100',
                'gender'                => 'required',
                'tax_number'            => 'required|max:10|min:10',
                'compamy_name'          => 'required|max:100|min:2',
                'tax_administration'    => 'required|max:200',
            ];
        }
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required'             => 'İsim Zorunludur.',
            'name.max'                  => 'İsim Maksimum 100 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'surname.required'          => 'Soyisim Zorunludur.',
            'surname.max'               => 'Soyisim Maksimum 100 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'email.required'            => 'Email Zorunludur.',
            'email.max'                 => 'Email Maksimum 50 Karakter İçermelidir.',
            'email.unique'              => 'Email Daha Önce Kullanılmıştır.',
            'password.required'         => 'Şifre Zorunludur.',
            'password.max'              => 'Şifre Maksimum 12 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'password.confirmed'        => 'Şifreler Birbiriyle Uyuşmamaktadır.',
            'phone.required'            => 'Telefon Zorunludur.',
            'phone.max'                 => 'Telefon Maksimum 15 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'image.max'                 => 'Resim Maksimum 2 MB Boyutunda Olmalıdır.',
            'image.mimes'               => 'Resim JPEG , JPG ve PNG Formatında Olmalıdır.',
            'image.image'               => 'Resim Bir Fotoğraf Olmalıdır.',
            'id_no.required'            => 'Vatandaşlık Numarası Zorunludur.',
            'id_no.max'                 => 'Vatandaşlık Numarası Maksimum 16 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'address.required'          => 'Adres Zorunludur.',
            'address.max'               => 'Adres Maksimum 250 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'country.required'          => 'Ülke Zorunludur.',
            'country.max'               => 'Ülke Maksimum 100 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'county.required'           => 'Şehir Zorunludur.',
            'county.max'                => 'Şehir Maksimum 100 Karakter Olmalıdır.',
            'gender.required'           => 'Cinsiyet Zorunludur.',
            'tax_number.required'       => 'Vergi Numarası Zorunludur.',
        ];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
public function rules(User $user)
{
    $rules = [
        // general rules
    ];

    if (1 === $user->account_type) {
        // add rules for account_type = 1
        // e.g.
        $rules['tax_number'] = 'required|max:10';
    } else {
        // add rules
    }

    return $rules;
}
```